# CSV Type Provider, Filtring the sequence

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am trying to get started with Type Provider,

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.2.3/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

// Define your library scripting code here
let customers = new CsvProvider<"Data/customer.csv">()

let cust = customers.Filter(fun row -> row.Email = "john.doe@foobar.com").Rows |> Seq.head
```

With a simple csv file :

```
last_name, first_name, date_of_birth, email, salaire, balance Doe,
John, 1982/10/08, john.doe@foobar.com, 2000, -1000 Ann, Mary,
1975/03/11, mary.ann@foobar.com, 5000, 10000 White, Bary, 1968/01/24,
white@bary.com, 10000, 150000
```

The code written is supposed to get John Doe customer, but I don't know why that's don't work... I tried many other ways to make it works, any idea ?

Comment: How is this not workng?

Comment: Exception when Seq.head is called (System.ArgumentException: The input sequence was empty.)

Comment: Have you checked what is actually in the seq without the filter?

Comment: Yes @JohnPalmer, the data is correcly loaded (but when I debugged, I saw the wrong column names item1, item2, item3... isntead First_name, Email...)

Comment: and if you print the emails?

Comment: works @JohnPalmer, but filtering not (when I do a loop and check equality don't works too)

Comment: is the sample really your csv? it seems odd - you either left out the breaks or it's mallformed

Comment: My guess then is probably whitespace or word Unicode somewhere

Comment: You are right, I just dropped all whitespaces and it works :-/. Thanks for your helps

Comment: @Carsten weired, the C/P didn't worked well